# is it possible to 'Swap' partial views on a button click?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, partial-views

I currently have a parent view with a design like below:

```
+----------------------------------------------+
|                    |           ___           |
|      ^             |          |   \          |
|     / \            |          |___/          |
|    /---\           |          |   \          |
|   /     \          |          |___/          |
|                    |                         |
|--------------------+-------------------------|  <--- Over View Of Page layout
|                    _____                     |
|                   /                          |
|                  |                           |
|                  |                           |
|                   \_____                     |
+----------------------------------------------+
```

Where A, B and C 'sections' are made up of partial views.

Within my A section, I have two buttons and (currently) a single partial view:

```
+----------------------------------------------+--------------------------------
| BUTTON 1   | BUTTON 2  |                     |
|------------------------+---------------------|               ______ 
|                                              |              |      \
|           <content here>                     |              |       |   
|                                              |              |       |         
|                                              |              |------/        
|                                              |              |      \_________          
|                                              |           __________/
|                                         _____|__________/
|                       _________________/
|         _____________/
|________/

                   ^
                   |
                   |
        Close up of 'A' section
```

I currently have button 1 being pressed and toggling the visibility of this view, using:

**HTML**

```
<button class="myBtn" onclick="toggle_visibility('btn1Partial');">Arm Details</button><a>
```

**Javascript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function toggle_visibility(id) {
       var e = document.getElementById(id);
       if(e.style.display == 'block')
          e.style.display = 'none';
       else
          e.style.display = 'block';
    }
</script>
```

However, i cannot find a way of achieving this with the second button such that the first partial view is 'removed' (not hidden), and another to take its place.

I'm certain there's a way to do this 'properly', using the MVC pattern, but i can't seem to find it! :(

All i want to do is 'swap' the content from section A with another partial view (much like a tab really, but the partial views will need to be 'recalled' when they 'reappear' to display most updated info - so simply hiding/showing won't really work here).

Any suggestions?

**Edit**

An alternative direction of this question could also be 'How to delete a partial view and open another in its place?'

Comment: If page postback is okay, then in the controller define an action for the second button, and when the action executes render the partial view you want.

Comment: that still doesn't solve the 'Hello, I'm a view that's already here' part of the question. I has to **remove the previous view** realistically.

Comment: @MrCoder - yes, that's right.  In my answer below, the load call will replace what's inside the placeholder div with no postback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be a common confusion. Views, partial views, etc. only apply when you're server-side. Once your page has been rendered in the client's browser it's just a web page. It doesn't matter how many partial views you had where, it's all just HTML at that point.

So, when you talk about replacing an area on this page, you're talking about swapping DOM elements. That means you need to use JavaScript to select some element like a `div` that contains the content you want to replace. Then, somehow get some new HTML content, and add this to the DOM where the element you selected is. This HTML can be created on page or you might go back to the server via AJAX to fetch it. In your scenario, you're looking at using AJAX.

To use AJAX, you need an endpoint on your server that will return a bit of HTML. In ASP.NET MVC terms, that means you need an action that returns `PartialView`.

Comment: hi Chris. Cheers for the clarification. However, could you possibly explain what do you mean by 'endpoint on your sever'? (btw sorry if that's a stupid question, but I haven't used AJAX at all before :3

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. The next sentence is a clarification, though. You need some action in some controller that will return `PartialView`. In other words, it will render a partial view with some model you pass in, and return that as HTML to your AJAX, which you can then use to insert into the DOM where you want it.

Comment: the fault was with me, not you :P. As for the problem, you've helped make it clear with how to go about achieving this - i've just got to learn some AJAX (yay!)

Comment: AJAX is pretty easy. That is, at least, if you use some framework, which I highly suggest you do. Your example was vanilla JS, but jQuery is included by default in MVC projects. If you don't use it for anything else, I would at least use jQuery (or your library of choice) for the AJAX stuff. There's just a ton of boiler plate code to do AJAX with vanilla JS and far to easy too make a mistake.

Comment: looks like a ton of reading is required for me over the next few years... I didn't even know it was called 'vanillaJS'. The only reason I even know there are different 'types of js' is from looking at typescript (lets not start there ;3) But i'll look into using jquery/ajax stuff now cheers :P

Comment: "Vanilla JS" is not an official thing; that's just my way of referring to the standard, spec JavaScript without any additions. Something like jQuery *is* JavaScript, but it adds a ton of helpers  and such. In other words, jQuery is the Rocky Road to JavaScript's Vanilla, in ice cream terms. Also, things like CoffeeScript, TypeScript, etc. are different. Those are "pre-processing" languages. They're somewhat similar to JS, but *not* JS. However, you can "compile" them, for lack of a better word, into JS.

Comment: I don't particularly like rocky road, but I understand what you're saying. Still, it seems i've a long way to go! :P

Comment: Your explanation is nice, pictures are helpful; but examples are awesome. It would have been really nice for an example of click goto controller action and return that partial view .

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do this.

I have done this using the `jQuery load` function.

On button click, just `$('#idOfDivHere').load(url...)`

And it will plop it right into your placeholder div.  The url is normal `controller/action` etc. - whatever you want/need to get the html to drop into your placeholder.

Of course there is a possibility of whacking out your DOM if you load things in there that shouldn't be there, but if you're careful with your partial view, this should work fine.